# How to show something forms a base topologically speaking

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Consider the set of all open balls in $(X,d)$ as well as $\emptyset$. How would I show that together they form a base topologically speaking? I mean it seems rather straightforward. You have a collection of open sets (or balls) along with $\emptyset$ which is also open. Then if you take the union you should form a base right? Although I would like to mathematically write it down.

Comment: In order to show that these sets form a base you must prove that the intersection of $2$ of these sets can be written as a union of these sets, and secondly that the whole space is the union of all of these sets.

Comment: No, it's not right. Being a base for a topology means that the family of their unions satisfies the required properties for being a topology.

Comment: @alex which is indeed the case if these conditions are satisfied.

Comment: @drhab I never dreamt of objecting to what you wrote. Particularly because I started writing my comment before yours appeared.

Comment: @alex Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @drhab No problems... My "not right" referred to what the OP wrote.

Comment: @drhab But this incident made me realise it is better to always write whom a comment is addressed to, even when it is addressed to the OP.

Comment: @alex That is a good lesson for me too.

Comment: Hmm I am a little lost. If we just have an arbitrary metric space $(X,d)$ how would I prove what you just said? I feel like it is more leaning towards using the definitions of what a bases is.

Comment: You can do what drhab said or you can use this theorem: If $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of open subsets of $X$ such that for every open set $U$: for every $x \in U$  there is a set $C \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C \in U$, then $\mathcal{C}$ is a base for the topology.  In other words, you can just pick an arbitrary open set of the space, pick an arbitrary point of that open set and then show that there is an open ball contained in the open set and that ball contains the point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a set. A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ is a base for some (then uniquely determined) topology iff

1. $\cup \mathcal{B} = X$
2. For all $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, for all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there exists $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$, such that $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$

If then $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $\mathcal{B} = \{B(x, r): x \in X, r > 0 \}$, the collection of all open balls, does fulfill these conditions.

To check 1. we only need to notice that $x \in B(x,1) \in \mathcal{B}$, for every $x \in X$.

For 2. pick $B(p, r), B(q, s) \in \mathcal{B}$, and $x \in B(p,r) \cap B(q, s)$. Then $d(p, x) < r$ and $d(q, x) < s$. Then setting $ t = \min(r - d(p,x), s - d(q,x)) > 0$. Then $B(x, t) \subset B(p,r) \cap B(q, s)$, by the triangle inequality (check this!)